# Resizing of AS-based Flash app from FireFox vs. IE

Tags: javascript, flash, actionscript-3, actionscript-2

I have put in some controls to allow users to resize my Flash app via Javascript:

```
document.getElementById("flashApp").height*=1.25;
document.getElementById("flashApp").width*=1.25;
```

This works great in IE/Safari, but is ignored in Firefox. I know it's talking the the flash app and gets and sets the height/width vars ok, but the same code run in FireFox ignores the scaling. (It's not the DOC spec issue)

Any thoughts?

Bill

Answer (score 0):

Make sure you've got *flashApp* set in both **embed** and **object** tags. One browser might look for the id in the embed tag, while another uses object.

Comment: Yes. The proper tags are set. I'm definately talking to the Flash variables as they are set to the current contents, and can be updated, but they don't cause any change to the Flash app...

Comment: Use http://code.google.com/p/swfobject/ to embed flash file in html page ro be sure that you are embedding it properly.